# How to create new column dynamically in dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "empid" : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    "empname" : ['a', 'b','c','d','e','f'],
    "empcity" : ['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff']
})
df1

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "empid" : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    "empname" : ['a', 'b','m','d','n','f'],
    "empcity" : ['aa','bb','cc','ddd','ee','fff']
})
df2

df_all = pd.concat([df1.set_index('empid'),df2.set_index('empid')],axis='columns',keys=['first','second'])
df_all

df_final = df_all.swaplevel(axis = 'columns')[df1.columns[1:]]
df_final
```

Based on df_final data frame, need to create following output. here comparison column need to created dynamically for every identical column as i'm trying to compare two data frame(both data frame structure and column name are same) where number of columns are more than 300

[image]

Comment: In addition to approach by jezrael, you can get the comparisons directly by doing `df1==df2` after setting the `empid` as index. Then just add that comparison output into the `pd.concat`. More details in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Directly comparing 2 dataframes with `==`

You can do this with a simple `==` between two dataframes that you need to compare. Let's start with the original 2 dataframes `df1` and `df2` -

```
first = df1.set_index('empid')
second = df2.set_index('empid')
comparisons = first==second      #<---

output = pd.concat([first, second, comparisons], axis=1,keys=['first','second', 'comparisons'])

#Swapping level and reindexing, borrowed from Jezrael's excellent answer
output = output.swaplevel(axis=1).reindex(first.columns, axis=1, level=0)
print(output)
```

```
      empname                    empcity                   
        first second comparisons   first second comparisons
empid                                                      
1           a      a        True      aa     aa        True
2           b      b        True      bb     bb        True
3           c      m       False      cc     cc        True
4           d      d        True      dd    ddd       False
5           e      n       False      ee     ee        True
6           f      f        True      ff    fff       False
```

---

### Alternate approach with pandas groupby

In addition to the [excellent answer by jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70766726/4755954), I am adding an alternate way of doing this using pandas groupby.

1. Tranpose to get columns as row indexes
2. Groupby on first level which contains empcity and empname
3. Apply comparison between the 2 rows
4. Transpose back to columns
5. Add multi index columns by product of original columns and "comparisons"
6. Combine the two dataframes (original one and one with comparisons)
7. Use swaplevel and reindex to get the order of columns that you need

```
#create comparisons
comparisons = (df_all.T
                     .groupby(level=-1)
                     .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0]==x.iloc[1])
                     .T)

#add multi index columns
comparisons.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['comparison'],comparisons.columns])

#concatenate with original data
df_final = pd.concat([df_all, comparisons], axis='columns')

#Swapping level and reindexing, borrowed from Jezrael's excellent answer
df_final = (df_final.swaplevel(axis = 'columns')
                    .reindex(df1.set_index('empid')
                                .columns, axis=1, level=0))
print(df_final)
```

```
      empname                   empcity                  
        first second comparison   first second comparison
empid                                                    
1           a      a       True      aa     aa       True
2           b      b       True      bb     bb       True
3           c      m      False      cc     cc       True
4           d      d       True      dd    ddd      False
5           e      n      False      ee     ee       True
6           f      f       True      ff    fff      False
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for possible compare all levels columns `first` with `second`, create new column in [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and reshape back by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for original order:

```
#original ordering
orig = df1.columns[1:].tolist()
print (orig)
['empname', 'empcity']

df_final = (df_all.stack()
                  .assign(comparions=lambda x: x['first'].eq(x['second']))
                  .unstack()
                  .swaplevel(axis = 'columns')
                  .reindex(orig, axis=1, level=0))
print (df_final)
      empname                   empcity                  
        first second comparions   first second comparions
empid                                                    
1           a      a       True      aa     aa       True
2           b      b       True      bb     bb       True
3           c      m      False      cc     cc       True
4           d      d       True      dd    ddd      False
5           e      n      False      ee     ee       True
6           f      f       True      ff    fff      False
```

Comment: This is helpful. Just need one suggestion.. row 1 where columns are mention as emp city, empname.. no need to sort in alphabetical order.. can it be stopped?

Comment: @ashish - Answer was edited.

Comment: you have hit the bullseye.. many thanks :) :)

Comment: got to know something new here.. will do the research for these

Comment: Very well written answer, upvoted!

Comment: I added an additional way of doing this using groupby, inspired from your approach, but your approach is much more elegant :)

Comment: need clarification to understand, final output is dataframe or something else? and if need make column names list where comparions = False, how to work on it

Comment: @ashish - final output is `DataFrame`. For new question is possible post new question - input data, expected ouput and your code?

Comment: this was the last piece as i was not sure if it is dataframe as column name alignment is different and i was trying to make the list of column name where comparions = False

Comment: @ashish - yes, if I add next solution then all anotehr answers not match. So best create new question.

Comment: @jezrael added a new question 'How to filter column names from multiindex dataframe fir a specific condition?' 
please see

Comment: absolutely it was helpful.. accepted it.. thank you :)

Comment: @ashish - accepted means green tick, accepted was another answer, not me.

Answer (score 1):

(i) Use [`get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html) to get the label values for level 0

(ii) Iterate over the outcome of (i) and for each `level=0`, do element-wise comparison using [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) between `first` and `second`

(iii) use `sort_index` to sort columns in desired order

```
for level_0 in df_final.columns.get_level_values(0).unique():
    df_final[(level_0, 'comparison')] = df_final[(level_0, 'first')].eq(df_final[(level_0,'second')])
df_final = df_final.sort_index(level=0, sort_remaining=False, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
      empcity                   empname                  
        first second comparison   first second comparison
empid                                                    
1          aa     aa       True       a      a       True
2          bb     bb       True       b      b       True
3          cc     cc       True       c      m      False
4          dd    ddd      False       d      d       True
5          ee     ee       True       e      n      False
6          ff    fff      False       f      f       True
```